# How to store the input value to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

```
<input type="text" id="transaction_id_input" name="transaction_name">
```

Above is the value that I want to store in PHP variables so I can compare it in the MySQL data to display specific data. I try storing the input value also to a javascript `document.getElementByID("sampleID").value` then store it in a variable but it didn't also work, hoping you will help me solve this problem.

```
<form method="GET" id="reg" name="valid" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(
        $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]
    ); ?>">
    <input type="text" id="transaction_id_input" name="transaction_name">
        <div class="wrapper" >
            <div class="search-input">
              <a href="" target="_blank" hidden></a>         
              <input type="text" id="searchmodal" placeholder="Type to search..">          
              <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="card-header" id="cardheader2">
              List of Medicine Transaction
        </div><br><br>
        <div class="enrollbutton2">
            <a class="nav-link" id="transactioninfo_to_addtransan_class" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_transaction">Add Transaction
                <span>
                    <lord-icon
                        src="https://cdn.lordicon.com/mecwbjnp.json"
                        trigger="loop"
                        colors="primary:#ffffff,secondary:#ffffff"
                        stroke="70"
                        style="width:30px;height:30px">
                    </lord-icon>
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="tableholdermodal" id="transactiontable">
        <br><br><br><br>
        <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Transaction No.</th>
                <th scope="col">Medicine Code</th>
                <th scope="col">Supply</th>
                <th scope="col">Lot No.</th>
                <th scope="col">Expiration Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Inputed Date</th>          
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myModalTable">
    
            <?php
            include "pdo_connection2.php";
            $stm3 = $conn->query(
                "SELECT * FROM tbl_transaction WHERE transaction_medicinecode = '' "
            );
            $rows = $stm3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if (count($rows) > 0) {
                foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
                  <tr>
                        <td data-label='Transaction ID' value="<?php echo $row[
                            "transaction_id"
                        ]; ?>"><?php echo $row["transaction_id"]; ?></td>
                        <td data-label='Medicine Code' value="<?php echo $row[
                            "transaction_medicinecode"
                        ]; ?>"><?php echo $row["transaction_medicinecode"]; ?></td>
                        <td data-label='Supply' value="<?php echo $row[
                            "transaction_supply"
                        ]; ?>"><?php echo $row["transaction_supply"]; ?></td>
                        <td data-label='Lot No.' value="<?php echo $row[
                            "transaction_lotnum"
                        ]; ?>"><?php echo $row["transaction_lotnum"]; ?></td>
                        <td data-label='Expiration Date' value="<?php echo $row[
                            "transaction_expdate"
                        ]; ?>"><?php echo $row["transaction_expdate"]; ?></td>
                        <td data-label='Date Registered' value="<?php echo $row[
                            "transaction_date"
                        ]; ?>"><?php echo $row["transaction_date"]; ?></td>
                        <td data-label='Action'>
                          <button type="button" class="transaction_update_class" name="transaction_update_name" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalupdate_transactopn"  value="<?php echo $row[
                              "transaction_id"
                          ]; ?>">
                              <lord-icon
                                  src="https://cdn.lordicon.com/wloilxuq.json"
                                  trigger="loop"
                                  colors="primary:#fb0054,secondary:#f55b2a "
                                  stroke="70"
                                  style="width:55px;height:55px">
                              </lord-icon>
                          </button>
    
                          <button type="button" class="transaction_delete_class" name="transaction_delete_name" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModaldelete_transaction" value="<?php echo $row[
                              "transaction_id"
                          ]; ?>">
                              <lord-icon
                                  src="https://cdn.lordicon.com/gsqxdxog.json"
                                  trigger="loop"
                                  colors="primary:#fb0054,secondary:#f55b2a "
                                  stroke="70"
                                  style="width:55px;height:55px">
                              </lord-icon>
                          </button>
    
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  
                <?php }
            } else {
                 ?>
                <tr><td><h4 id="h4nodatafound">------ NO DATA FOUND ------</h4></td></tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
              
    
            </tbody>
          </table>
          
          </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: it didn't also work (typo sorry)

Comment: `getElementID` would need to be `getElementById`. And of course you would need to put the ID of the element as a string in between the brackets which follow. Always show us your exact code, not an approximation

Comment: But really if you want to send the value of the field to PHP and read it there, you just need to submit the form and write PHP code to read the form data. Almost any PHP/forms tutorial will show you what to do already.

Comment: i already try that sir sorry for the typo

Comment: i don't want to submit any form I just want to store the input value to the PHP variable btw the table is in a modal form

Comment: If you don't want to submit the form then you will need to send the data to the PHP via an AJAX request. PHP is server-side code...it does not run in the browser. Therefore, in order to activate PHP you need to make some sort of HTTP request to the server, whether that's submitting a form, clicking a link or sending an AJAX request

Comment: Yes that's correct, you do